# when use ng-include inside of ui-view get error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui

I using Angular.js for my application but when i use `ng-include` inside of `ui-view` like below I get this error:

`Error: e is null .after/<@http://localhost/vb-asli/js/angular.min.js:152:228 r@http://localhost/vb-asli/js/angular.min.js:7:288`

And my code is like this:

```
<div ui-view>
    <div  ng-include="'partials/menuPreview.html'">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you aren't supposed to put any child elements directly inside a `ui-view`.

I think you are misunderstanding how `ui-view` is supposed to be used. From the docs [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#ui-view) and [here](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.directive:ui-view) there is no mention of putting child elements directly inside of a `ui-view`.

I haven't looked into the code deeply enough but I can see that if you do put a `ng-include` inside of `ui-view`, the `ng-include` directly fails because the parent node is null, which leads me to believe that `ui-view` is clearing/removing any contents inside the element (or doing something similar).  And it makes sense it would do that because that is what it *will* be doing when switching routes/states.